# How to check if string has no vowel after 4 consecutive chars

Tags: php, regex, char, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to check if a user is entering something close to a valid name. So if it's entered something like `gbcvcvrt`, I would want to validate it and mark this as not a real name. Something like `theg+vowel` should be validated as the right name.

On any length of string the code should detect four consecutive non vowel alphabets. 
I don't expect anyone's name to be rhythm by the way

Consider

```
$String = 'therhythm';
```

We can't check for the first four chars, we have to go through the entire string and check four any four consecutive non-vowel alphabets regardless of where on the string they are  situated. That way we can validate $String as not valid even though the first five chars would validate it if we were checking the first four alphabets.

- Should also not contain 3 consecutive vowels,
- Should not contain numbers,
- Non Alphabetic chars

Comment: So `gbcvacvrt` would be valid? How does a vowel validate a name? It's pretty hard to tell what's "valid" from what's not, unless you use some sort of dictionary behind

Comment: Yes this is code, I'm doing minimum check, not writing the entire human language bot from every race.

Comment: So it is valid if any of the 1st 4 characters are vowels?

Comment: `Four consecutive non-vowels` or `Three consecutive vowels` anywhere in the string should be a good enough check for marking it as invalid i guess.

Comment: Which in JS would be `valid = !/[^aeiou]{4,}/.test(name) && !/[aeiou]{3,}/.test(name);`

Comment: No if a vowel follows four non-vowel alphabet on any kind of combination length... I don't expect anyone's name to be rhythm by the way.

Comment: That would get numbers and another stuff, though.

Comment: im glad my typical asdfasdf passes

Comment: @user3109875  I modified my code after you added more criterias . Try it.

Comment: Merckx and Schnell are actual family names. Bauer and Aoe ditto. This is just off the top of my head; actual research should bring many more counterexamples.

Comment: What about names with diacritics like `François` or `Müller`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because trying to validate people's names in any way sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @deceze +1; see also http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on your latest edit:** You can use following regex for this:

```
^(?!.*?[^aeiou]{5})(?!.*?[aeiou]{3})[a-z]*$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vM0aN9

Breaking it down:

- `[^aeiou]` => Match anything but vowels
- `(?!.*?[^aeiou]{5})` => Negative lookahead to make sure there is no case of 5 consecutive consonants
- `(?!.*?[aeiou]{3})` => To make sure there is no case of 3 consecutive vowels
- `[a-z]*` => To make sure there are only letters in the input

Comment: It would be nicer with some explanation.

Comment: Sure I will add some explanation to my question.

Comment: it will match `testteeee` with more than 3 consecutive `e` and `testttttttt` in the case of consecutive consonants.

Comment: ok check the updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$string = "gkwohtfeiak3d";

function checkstring($input){

    if(preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $input, $match) || preg_match("/[AEIOU]{3,}/i", $input, $match)){

            if(preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $input, $match)){
                    echo "Your string has numbers.<br/>";
            }

            if(preg_match("/[AEIOU]{3,}/i", $input, $match)){
                    echo "Your string has three or more consecutive vowels";
            }

    }else{

        $checkthis = substr($input, 4);

        if(preg_match("/[AEIOU]+/i", $checkthis, $match2)){
                echo "$input has vowels after the fourth character";
        }else{
                echo "$input has no vowels after the fourth character";
        }

    }
}

checkstring($string);
?>
```

Comment: what is this? Its return "$input has no vowels" ?

Comment: @voodoo417 It displayed properly on my server.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?![aeiou]{3,})(?:\D(?![^aeiou]{4,}[aeiou]*)(?![aeiou]{4,})){3,}$
```

This regex has all your conditions:

```
<?php
    $values = array(
            "test",
            "al",
            "beautiful",
            "eautiful",
            "mohsen",
            "ehsasssss",
            "a test",
            "yeeeeee",
            "test",
            "mohammad",
            "ali",
            "mohsen",
            "mohsenmlpl",
            "allllll",
            "allilllllo",
            "thisisatest",
            "zagros",
            "4o54o45646o",
            "therhythm",
            "theg+vowel",
            "gbcvcvrt",
            "user3109875",
        );
    foreach ($values as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "$value => ", preg_match("/^(?![aeiou]{3,})(?:\D(?![^aeiou]{4,}[aeiou]*)(?![aeiou]{4,})){3,}$/", $value)? "TRUE" : "FALSE", "\n";
    }
```

**Output**:

```
test => TRUE
al => FALSE
beautiful => TRUE
eautiful => FALSE
mohsen => TRUE
ehsasssss => FALSE
a test => TRUE
yeeeeee => FALSE
test => TRUE
mohammad => TRUE
ali => TRUE
mohsen => TRUE
mohsenmlpl => FALSE
allllll => FALSE
allilllllo => FALSE
thisisatest => TRUE
zagros => TRUE
4o54o45646o => FALSE
therhythm => FALSE
theg+vowel => TRUE
gbcvcvrt => FALSE
user3109875 => FALSE
```

Comment: This will match `:$)+abc`

Comment: @M42 yes it should. OP needs non-alphanumeric chars as well

Answer (score 0):

For your test string `asdfasdf` use the following regex:

```
([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{3}+)/ig
```

[Online Example](http://regex101.com/r/jZ0wV2)

It will catch 3 or more repeating consonants and you can test it in revered logic!

Using PHP you could try something like this:

```
function testString($data) {
    if (!preg_match('/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{3}+)/', $data)) {
        return 'Valid';
    } else {
        return 'Invalid';
    }
}
echo testString('asasacdDdfasdf');
echo '<br>';
echo testString('Ilia');
```

[Online Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8w5Sbd)